# What are some useful SQL statements / usage patterns that should be known by all developers who may touch the Back end side of the project?

Tags: sql, database, backend

What are some useful SQL statements that should be known by all developers who may touch the Back end side of the project?

(**Update:** just like in algorithm, we know there are sorting problems, shuffling problems, and we know some solutions to them.  This question is aiming at the same thing).

For example, one I can think of are:

> Get a list of Classes that are not
>   registered by any students.  (Outer
>   join and check whether the match is
>   NULL, or by Get from Classes table,
>   all ClassIDs which are NOT IN (a
>   subquery to get all ClassIDs from the
>   Registrations table))

Are there some SQL statements that should be under the sleeve of all developers that might touch back end data?

Comment: I feel it's like asking, "Is there a Java snippet everybody should know about?" My opinion is that there's no SQL statement you need to know, only SQL syntax you need to know. Besides, who tells you any generic statement will be valid for your specific tables layout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119859/questions-every-good-database-sql-developer-should-be-able-to-answer

Comment: DROP DATABASE... very useful.

Comment: maybe it is just like, knowing there are the "sorting" problems, or shuffling problems, and what are the solutions to them.  This question is aiming to find out something like that for SQL and Databases.

Comment: I see. but that is not how the question was phrased.

Comment: I like this question, we don't think about query patterns enough.

Comment: There are a LOT of potential answers to this question. Maybe we should combine the 'pattern' and 'sql' tags to document *specific* SQL patterns as separate questions instead of trying to do so in just one question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm generalizing what types of queries you should be able to write.

1. First a straight up select with no
   joins (and no select *)
2. You should know how to combine two
   or more tables and get records that
   are in all the tables
3. You should know how to combine two
   or more tables and get records that
   are in all the tables but return
   only one record from the table with
   the many side of the one-to-many
   relationship
4. You should be able to get the
   records in one table but not in an
   associated table
5. You should be able to Aggregate data
   for a report
6. You should be able to insert one
   record to a table
7. You should be able to update one
   record in a table
8. You should be able to delete one
   record in a table
9. You should be able to insert a group
   of records to a table without a
   cursor
10. You should be able to update a
     group of records in a table without
     a cursor
11. You should be able to delete a
     group of records in a table without
     a cursor
12. You should be able to perform
     multiple actions in one transaction
     and handle error trapping
13. You should be able to create union
     of records and know when to use
     UNION vice UNION ALL
14. You should be able to vary the data
     for one field based on some
     criteria (using CASE)
15. You should be able to write an IF
     Statement.

Well that's what springs to mind immedaitely. This is for a beginner SQL developer of course. This includes nothing I would consider advanced.

Answer (score 6):

Developers should learn the principles of databases and SQL. Not any specific SQL statements as SQL statements required will change depending on what the database stores and the structure of the database.

Update: Your updated question is interesting. I am thinking SQL statements in general are quite simple. So they are not worth memorising. If they are complex then they are tied to a specific problem and again are not worth memorising.

Comment: Agreed. Understanding is always better than memorising.

Comment: But there are patterns of problems to solve that you should know how to handle, so that you can solve the specific problems.

Comment: @HLGEM But even in your answer below you did not mention patterns specific to SQL you mentioned queries that a reasonably proficient database developer should know. So are there patterns specific to SQL worth remembering? As I said it is an interesting question.

Comment: I think I listed various types of query patterns not specific queries. If you know how to do type 10 on my list, then no matter what the database structure, you can create a set-based update.

I think it was interesting enough, I'm writing up Wiki entries at a another site (http://lessthandot.com/) to discuss what a beginning dev should know to understand the query pattern. I'll update my answer later when they are done.