# What's the best way to prepare for a technical interview focusing on T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I have a job interview coming that will focus on T-SQL and general SQL competency.

Any suggestions on how to prepare for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always ask a question that can be solved either set-based or with a cursor to see if they know not to use the cursor. I'd want to see explicit joins and not implicit joins in any code samples. I'd want to see that you don't use select *. I'd ask about performance tuning. I'd want to know if you understand the difference between the various join types.

Here are some basic types of query patterns you should know and be able to discuss or provide sample code for :
[What are some useful SQL statements / usage patterns that should be known by all developers who may touch the Back end side of the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701479/what-are-some-useful-sql-statements-usage-patterns-that-should-be-known-by-all/2701641#2701641)

Comment: Great list! Do you know of any books that give examples of all of the types of queries you list at that link?

Comment: Pretty much any standard t-sql book should have examples of most of those, but just not listed that way. I've started to write Wiki aritcles on them but only have three so far, but other articles here might help you as well: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Category:Microsoft_SQL_Server

Answer (score 1):

Read up on

- Normalization and it's forms.
- Indexing
- Table relations
- Keys
- DataTypes
- Transactions
- Locks
- Constraints
- UDF's

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SQL Server Quiz, Can You Answer All These?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-quiz-can-you-answer-all-these)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of websites that list questions that others have encountered (along with the answers):

[Sybase Interview Questions](http://www.geekinterview.com/Interview-Questions/Database/Sybase)

[Sybase tips](http://sites.google.com/site/sumedhshende/sybase)