# using group_concat with other selection criteria - mySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, group-concat

I have two tables, arrc_PurchActivity and arrc_Voucher. The purchase activity table contains multiple records per purchase, tied together by the credit card authorization. I need to return a single row per purchase, plus pull in a field from the voucher table. 
If I just grab a few fields from the purchase activity table, like this:

```
SELECT group_concat( VoucherID ) , CcAuthCode FROM arrc_PurchaseActivity GROUP BY CcAuthCode
```

it works fine, returning something like this:

```
group_concat( VoucherID )  | CcAuthCode
=========================================
610643,611139,610642       | 8LUPDN
```

What I need to do is pull in another contatenated field (VoucherNbr), this time from the arrc_Voucher table, where the voucher table's VoucherID is equal to the purchase table's VoucherID. In this case, because VoucherID is a concatenation, I need to return a concatenated column of VoucherNbr for each VoucherID in the concatenated column. Clear as mud, right? What I need would look like this:

```
group_concat( VoucherID )  | group_concat( VoucherNbr)  |  CcAuthCode
===========================|============================|=============
610643,611139,610642       | 123,456,789                |  8LUPDN
```

In other words, the VoucherNbr for VoucherID 610643 is 123, VoucherNbr for 611139 is 456, etc.

Can anyone help me out? This is way over my head...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT pa.ccauthcode,
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pa.voucherid) AS voucherids,
          GROUP_CONCAT(v.vouchernbr) AS vouchernbrs
     FROM ARRC_PURCHASEACTIVITY pa 
LEFT JOIN ARRC_VOUCHER v ON v.voucherid = pa.voucherid
 GROUP BY pa.ccauthcode
```

I specified the `DISTINCT` in the GROUP_CONCAT for the voucherid's because it's possible you'd have multiple vouchernbr's to a voucherid.  If not, remove the DISTINCT.

The LEFT JOIN ensures you'll get `ARRC_PURCHASEACTIVITY` records that do not have supporting records in `ARRC_VOUCHER`.  Change "LEFT JOIN" to "JOIN" if you don't want this behavior.

Comment: Thank you! Up until these past few weeks, my need for sql has been fairly limited, and my experience is also fairly limited - to basic select from where-type statements.

Comment: can you recommend a good book or website tutorial that would help me get past the basics? I'm pretty sure you've answered a few of my other questions this last month. I've done the www.w3schools.com tutorial, but it's pretty simple. I know there are a lot of reference sites, but you kind of have to know what you're looking for to make use of a reference.

Comment: @EmmyS: You're welcome.  Sorry, I'm not familiar with more advanced tutorials.  The problem is that answers depend on the database, table design (incl. data types), data and the expected result. I'm still tweaking [my list of categorizing SQL functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119859/questions-every-good-database-sql-developer-should-be-able-to-answer/2120339#2120339), but I'd start with focusing on problems dealing with the basics.

Comment: Thanks. That's a great thread; although I have no desire to be an actual database developer, as a web developer I do need to be able to write queries on databases provided by clients. Your list (and a few of the other posts) give me some specific things to look at.

Comment: @EmmyS: Come to the Dark.. er, Database Side.  We have cookies =)