# Database interview/Practical questions?

Tags: database, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions every good Database/SQL developer should be able to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119859/questions-every-good-database-sql-developer-should-be-able-to-answer)

Looking for some good questions to be asked for in Database `interview / practical lab` exam.
The topics I need to study include **pl/sql**(*cursor*, *procudeures*, *trigger*), **sql queries**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119859/questions-every-good-database-sql-developer-should-be-able-to-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this blog post many times in the past, the good thing is not only do they provide the questions, but also the answers!

http://sql-plsql.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-interview-questions.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

www.plsqlchallenge.com

Whole host of questions and answers, ranked from beginner to advanced.