# What's a good book for introduction to databases for web developers

Tags: php, mysql, database, e-commerce

A book that is an introduction to databases and geared towards web developers.

Comment: Might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119859/questions-every-good-database-sql-developer-should-be-able-to-answer/2120339#2120339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really liked this book, was clear, concise and informative.

[http://www.amazon.com/PHP-MySQL-Web-Development-4th/dp/0672329166](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166)

Comment: +1, That is a great book for getting started with PHP and MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Naturally, you want [The Manga Guide to Databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271905). :D

Answer (score 0):

[Database Design for Mere Mortals: A Hands-On Guide to Relational Database Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201752840) by Michael J. Hernandez